# If an algorithm's running time can be expressed as function F(x)=√n+(logn)^2 ,

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

If an algorithm's running time can be expressed as function `F(x)=√n+(logn)^2` , then which one of the following is not a correct bound for the running time ?

```
1. O(n)
2. O(√n)
3. O(log(n)^2)
4. Omega(1)
```

Comment: Have you read anything about complexity? It would very useful for your homework.

Comment: Hi there, you're not asking in the right place. I advise you go ask there: http://math.stackexchange.com/ or

Comment: @J.Chomel: I disagree: Time complexity belongs to computer science, not primarily to math. Have edited the tags, however.

Answer (score 1):

When the time complexity of an algorithm consists of multiple terms (here `√n` and `(log n)^2`), you can ignore all term except the one that gets largest for large `n`.

In this case, it can be shown that `√n` >> `(log n)^2` for sufficiently large `n`. Therefore the complexity is `O(√n)`. This should provide enough information for you to answer the question.

However this is a bit of a special case, because `n` really needs to get *very* large until the 2nd term really can be ignored. So you should keep in mind that Big-O complexity makes a theoretical statement and is *not always* practically significant.